# Azure Custom Policies KMSI - Password Reset and Cancel Sign up redirect to authentication response url

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-ad-b2c

I use this [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi) for a B2C web app/web api authentication/authorisation. I also use Local Account [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started?tabs=app-reg-preview#create-the-signing-key) and [KMSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-keep-me-signed-in).

The issue I have is that when a user clicks forgot pwd or cancel sign up the web app redirects to the authentication redirect url (in my case xxx/azurewebsites.net/api/UserAccess) without authenticating :

[image]

The B2C [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi) (although it was setup for User Flows and I'm using Custom Policies) already handles error exceptions when a user clicks "forgot password" - I use this same code. However my web app picks up error AADB2C90118 (click forgot password) but OnAuthenticationFailed redirects it to the authentication response url without performing authentication.

Below is Fiddler showing my webapp behaviour: click on forgot password->picks up the error->redirects to authentication response URL without authentication:

[image]
And here MSFT's [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi): click on forgot password->picks up error->redirects back to authentication:

[image]

Below my Start.Auth OnAuthenticationFailed, I added error AADB2C90091 to cater when the user clicks to Sign up and cancels.:

```
private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
        {
            notification.HandleResponse();

            // Handle the error code that Azure AD B2C throws when trying to reset a password from the login page
            // because password reset is not supported by a "sign-up or sign-in policy"
            if (notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription != null && notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
            {
                // If the user clicked the reset password link, redirect to the reset password route
                notification.Response.Redirect("/Account/ResetPassword");
                notification.Response.Redirect("/");
            }
            else if (notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription != null && notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription.Contains("AADB2C90091"))
            {
                // If the user clicked the Cancel for reset password or sign up link, redirect to login page
                notification.Response.Redirect("/Account/SignUpSignIn");
            }
            else if (notification.Exception.Message == "access_denied")
            {
                notification.Response.Redirect("/");
            }
            else
            {
                notification.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + notification.Exception.Message);
            }
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
```

In using [Custom Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started?tabs=app-reg-preview#create-the-signing-key) and [KSMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-keep-me-signed-in) tutorial standard files with the changes explained in the tutorial; I'm not sure if these changes would have an impact on this issue I'm finding. I attach link to xml files https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1E9SRLaicM74YmxDxNL1_rfx4NPvX-ADJ?usp=sharing

Comment: Is your custom policy in development mode? like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights#configure-the-custom-policy). It might be preventing the HTTP 302, instead showing the error to you.

Comment: thanks for the thought @Jas Suri, it's in production doesn't have app insights interfere from what I can see